# Сумма прописью на польском

Tags: алгоритм

Есть задача, для одной международной компании, в фактурах печатать сумму прописью. Не могу найти вариант на польском языке.
Подскажите решение, кто знает.

Answer (score 2):

Некоторое изучение вопроса словообразования числительных в польском языке наталкивает на мысль, что оно один в один совпадает со словообразованием в русском. Посему достаточно найти алгоритм записи числа русскими словами (например, [этот](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/misc/sumwrite.php)), и заменить их на польские (берём [отсюда](http://speakasap.com/ru/pl-chislitelnye.html)). Конечно, ввиду моего поверхностного знания польского, я могу ошибаться, и вам стоит проконсультироваться с носителем языка, лингвистом или просто человеком, который знает польский достаточно хорошо. Однако, вряд ли вы найдёте такого человека на русскоязычном форуме, посвящённом программированию.